# Join queries for jsonb fields

Tags: postgresql, left-join, jsonb

Can anyone help me with a join query for tables with jsonb fields?

If I have two tables and each has a jsonb column `value` and I need to run some join queries.

Let's say `value` field in each table has rows similar to this

`accounts`

```
[{
      "account-id":"c3ff14f9-b9ce-4daf-930b-3500e0efbdc9",
      "name": "foo"
  }...]
```

`account-balances`

```
[{
    "account-id": "c3ff14f9-b9ce-4daf-930b-3500e0efbdc9",
    "amount": 31415926
}...]
```

You can see that data in tables is associated via "account-id" property.
Now I need to find all accounts that have corresponding balance > 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM accounts JOIN "account-balances"
              ON accounts.value->'account-id'="account-balances".value->'account-id'
WHERE ("account-balances".value->>'amount')::integer>0;
```